# Truncate dating when moving from staging to relational tables

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know that snowflake has the ENFORCE_LENGTH and TRUNCATECOLUMNS options when copying data into a staging table, however I read that this is only for CSV data (not 100% that is true though). Regardless, my issue is that the workflow I have is this

Load json data to staging table (st) in one big column

Run INSERT INTO column (A, B, C) SELECT st:data:A, st:data:B, st:data:C FROM st;

Where column A is varchar 200, b is varchar 400, c is varchar 600

Because the data we load is variable sometimes one of the three columns is too large and the insert fails. Is there a way to enforce and truncate the length on each of these columns for their respective sizes? I'd like to avoid blindly truncating all of the data we stage or blindly increasing the size of all of our columns.

Comment: Those parameters are used when COPYing data from an external source into a table; you seem to be INSERTing data from one table into another, so those parameters aren’t relevant. If you want to limit the size of data in a specific column then why not use LEFT/SUBSTR in your SELECT statement?

Comment: I am doing both, copying from an external source to a staging table and then inserting it. I could use SUBSTR but I was hoping for a better way than going back and substringing all of the various INSERT statements as its a fairly large code base

Comment: Yes, but the COPY process is irrelevant to your issue, isn’t it? You only have an issue with data lengths when inserting data? What is your definition of a “better way” i.e. what criteria would an answer have to meet in order for you to consider it?

Comment: I was hoping there was a command along the lines of INSERT TRUNCATE INTO... that would just auto truncate data to match the size of the column I'm adding it to rather than going through and adding left(column, size) for every column as that is a much more painstaking process